# Positive dependence and functions of random variables

Tags: probability, association-measure

Is there a notion of positive dependence such that if $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ are positively dependent, then for any two functions, $a\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)$ and $b\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)$, that are increasing in all arguments, $a\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)$ and $b\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)$ are positively dependent?

For an example of what I mean by a positive dependence assumption, this is one such assumption:

$\text{pr}\left\{ X_{1} \le u_{1}, \dots, X_{n-1} \le u_{n-1} | X_{n} = x\right\}$ is decreasing in $x$ where we could let any of the random variables be $X_{n}$.

EDIT: I think this was a little too vague.  Here's an example of a notion of positive dependence that works to explain what I mean.  I want to know if there are other examples.

Say, positive dependence means the covariance of any two increasing functions of $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ is positive.  Then, $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ being positively dependent implies $\text{cov}\left(a\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right), b\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)\right)\ge 0$.

Are $a$ and $b$ positively dependent?  To answer, I check whether the covariance of any increasing function of $a$ and $b$ is positive: $\text{cov}\left(\hat{a}\left(a,b\right),\hat{b}\left(a,b\right)\right)\ge 0$.

Because increasing compositions are increasing, the composition of $\hat{a}$ and $\left(a,b\right)$ is increasing in $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$.  Therefore, the above covariance is positive and $a$ and $b$ are positively dependent.

Are there other examples?

Comment: Are you looking for the "Multivariate Likelihood Ratio Order", and multivariate total positivity of order 2 (MTP2)? Check out for example the book Shaked and Shanthikumar: "Stochastic Orders", Chapter 6.E and references therein, in particular Karlin and Rinott.